# How do you extract number of current date in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

How to extract the number of current month-day in Cocoa?
That's how I do this but it returns something like 309420938420422..
thanks!

```
-(int)getNumberOfCurrentDay:(NSDate*)date_
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:date_];
    NSInteger numberday = [comps day];

    NSLog(@"Number of the day %i", numberday);


    return numberday;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `NSDayCalendarUnit` instead of `NSMonthCalendarUnit`. Or do the following to get more(days, months, years, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.):

```
int comp = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *theDateComponents = [gregorian components:comp fromDate:date_];
int day = [theDateComponents day];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You need to use: *NSDayCalendarUnit*

```
-(int)getNumberOfCurrentDay:(NSDate*)date_
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date_];
    NSInteger numberday = [comps day];

    NSLog(@"Number of the day %d", numberday);


    return numberday;
}
```